# capture sum of null

Tags: sql, sql-server, hive

how to capture the sum of null of an attribute(bit_id) by date and company

Comment: What do you mean the "sum of null"? The `SUM` of `NULL` is `NULL`.... No matter *how many* `NULL`s you aggregate, the final value will be `NULL`. `SELECT SUM(CONVERT(int,N)) FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N);` returns `NULL`.

Comment: You've also tagged both [[tag:sql-server]] and [[tag:hive]] here, which are *completely* different database products. Please only tag the technologies you are *really* using.

Answer (score 0):

If what you mean is you want to *count* how many values are `NULL` for each date/company, then you can just use a `CASE` statement wrapped in a `SUM`:

```
declare @dataTable table (
    recordDate date,
    company varchar(100),
    attribute bit
)

insert into @dataTable values
('2021-09-28','CompanyA',null),
('2021-09-28','CompanyA',null),
('2021-09-28','CompanyA',1),
('2021-09-28','CompanyB',0),
('2021-09-28','CompanyB',null),
('2021-09-29','CompanyA',0),
('2021-09-29','CompanyB',1),
('2021-09-29','CompanyA',null),
('2021-09-29','CompanyB',null),
('2021-09-29','CompanyB',null),
('2021-09-29','CompanyB',null)

select
    recordDate,
    company,
    sum(case when attribute is null then 1 else 0 end) as countNULLs
from @dataTable
group by recordDate, company
order by recordDate, company
```

Results:

```
/------------------------------------\
| recordDate | company  | countNULLs |
|------------|----------|------------|
| 2021-09-28 | CompanyA |      2     |
| 2021-09-28 | CompanyB |      1     |
| 2021-09-29 | CompanyA |      1     |
| 2021-09-29 | CompanyB |      3     |
\------------------------------------/
```